# Quantifying the load on SQL Server 2008 from brute force attacks?

Tags: sql-server-2008, brute-force, sa

I have a SQL 2008 box that has been the recent target of brute force attacks on the "sa" account (silly kids . . .). Is it possible to quantify the server load of a single attempt at logging in to SA with a bad password on an account that is also disabled? I'm mostly interested in CPU load and I'd have to do it retroactively since that box has been taken offline. I don't have to have an exact value, just a value that I can use as a heuristic and extrapolate out to the number of requests.

Comment: Why is your SQL Server exposed to the script kiddies? Your first priority is to get that server off of any public-facing node. If it needs to be open to the Internet at large (and in fact to protect your entire network), your best bet is not to try and quantify the load they're causing (this is like trying to figure out if two polar bears or three polar bears chewed your arm off), but invest in some hardware that will detect and prevent intrusion. At my last gig we had really good success with Mazu gear. Mazu has since been bought out by Riverbed http://www.riverbed.com/

Comment: Well unless you were actively collecting performance metrics and have all the logs going back to count up login requests / login failures etc., I don't think there's much you can do post-mortem.

Comment: I'd agree, it's hard to figure out after the fact. If you have the complete logs, it's fairly trivial to cook up a perl script to count entries in the logs matching a certain pattern, so you could get a true count rather than trying to do fuzzy math. This sort of information could be used to engineer an attack that falls below the threshold of detectability, so it might be dangerous to really get into it in public anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to prevent Brute Force Attack on SQL Server is to disable its remote access and don't expose it on to the internet.

http://iskrov.info/2013/11/how-to-disable-remote-access-microsoft-sql-server/